# Циклический сдвиг влево на k значений

Tags: c, циклы

У меня такое задание:

> в матрице сдвинуть элементы строк циклическим сдвигом влево так, чтобы максимальный элемент был расположен на главной диагонали.

С нахождением максимума и самим циклическим сдвигом у меня вроде как не возникло проблем, но вот  как именно расчитать шаг, на который нужно сдвинуть строку, я немного не могу понять.
Можете подсказать как это лучше сделать, а то у меня k оочень криво считается, и неправильно.

Код прилагаю (он частичный, т.к. это в функции будет)

```
int k = 0, j_max;
float max;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    max = -1000;
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if (M[i][j] > max) 
            j_max = j;
    }
    k = 0;
    if (j_max >= i) k = j_max - i;
    else k = n - j_max + 1;

    while(k > 0) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n-1; j++){
            float temp = M[i][j];
            M[i][j] = M[i][j + 1];
            M[i][j + 1] = temp;
        }
        k--;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну если я правильно вас понял, то сдвигать нужно на `max_index - row_length`, если число отрицательно, то добавьте еще `row_length`. Это если у вас сдвиг справа налево происходит. Но судя по коду я вас не так понял.

Comment: Да, у меня сдвиг справа налево. Но если попробовать вашим методом, он неправильно расчитает. Если max_index - 4 , а нужно чтобы на 1, row_lenght = 8. Тогда k = 4, но должно быть 3

Comment: Ой! Да я ошибся там от `max_index` вычитаться индекс строки должен. Тогда `max_index - row_index = 4 - 1 = 3`